# Gavin & Stacy inside jokes & nicknames

Tags: dialogue, gavin-and-stacy

My girlfriend is subtitling in a foreign language for an academic exercise and has come across two particular challenges relating to an episode of Gavin & Stacy. Neither of us have watched the series before and I am wondering if there are some inside jokes or themes or background prior to season 3 episode 6 that would give context. I'm a native English speaker who was born and grew up in the UK and I don't understand this.

## Clip 1

In this particular episode (full transcript here) https://subsaga.com/bbc/comedy/gavin-and-stacey/series-3/episode-6.html

They find out they are having a baby.

> 0:17:43
>   I love you so much.
>   I love you too, baby.
>   BOTH: It's just the way it is. PHONE RINGS

What is the relevance/significance of them both simultaneously saying " It's just the way it is" at the same time? Is it a song with significance or a phrase relating to them discovering they are having a baby?

## Clip 2

> 0:12:21
>   Hey, hot dog!
>   Bryn burger!
>   How you doing?
>   Ohhh! Ho, ho, ho!
>   And who's this little nugget? What a treat!

Personally I've never really heard nicknames like "hot dog", "burger" and "nugget". They obviously all have in common that they are food. Urban/slag dictionaries would have me believe

hot dog = cool (http://onlineslangdictionary.com/search/?q=hot+dog&sa=Search)

nugget = uncool/jerk/crazy: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/search/?q=nugget&sa=Search

Burger=someone who sucks at simple tasks. https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Burger

Is there more to it than this? Personally I wouldn't have understood any of these nicknames.

Comment: The time references aren't really necessary here. Personally, I'm not sure M&TV is the right place for this. We have dedicated sites relating to English Language usage which would seem to be more appropriate.

Comment: Time references might be if people are watching the clips for extra context on tone of voice and the way the words are spoken and used. I don't feel the only thing at play here is necessarily just english language usage - since I've never seen the show as stated in OP, for all I know, episodes prior to season 3 episode 6 might have introduced these phrases, nicknames and sayings as inside jokes or something with context to the Gavin and Stacy story, so perhaps this has nothing to do with English language usage

Comment: @Paulie_D The initial intent of the question is actually on topic ("I am wondering if there are some inside jokes or themes or background prior to season 3 episode 6 that would give context" => asks for context of the show itself), but the posted examples are asking for out-of-universe references which does indeed make it off-topic IMO. However, the first example could possibly be an in-universe reference but OP should clarify that in the question.

Comment: I think Bryn Burger is just an alliterative use of the word burger, both start with the letter B. Nugget refers to a Chicken Nugget a common fast food item. A little nugget would be a smaller person that is with Bryn. All three phrases Hot Dog, Burger and Nugget are to do with fast food that is commonly eaten in the UK.I am not sure that the two slang dictionary references apply here. It's quite a common speech pattern in the UK to use a nickname and reinforce it using similar terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen a few episodes of this show.  I don't believe that there's necessarily a set reason or origin explained for these and many other turns of phrase.  It's a meld of how young Essex and Welsh people speak and there's made-up words and phrases that families and close groups make up and use.

> It's just the way it is

Is a reflection on Gavin and Stacey living so far apart and a phrase that they use often to combat the sense of separation they have - saying the phrase together emotionally unites them.

Hot-dog and nugget - they're just pet-names that people have for each other.

A lot of things involving Bryn can be taken as innuendo.